# How do modules like babel, eslint, or jshint read it's configuration (*rc) files?

Tags: node.js

You know, babel take configuration from `.babelrc` file in current project root
directory. Eslint, jshint and the other do the same thing. How did those modules do that?

I mean, I know some workaround to do the same thing. I just want to know how to do it right. How I do this is like this:

```
const getConfigPath = () => {
    let cwd = process.cwd();
    while (cwd !== '/') {
        try {
            let configPath = path.join(cwd, '.configrc');
            fs.accessSync(configPath, fs.R_OK);
            return configPath;
        } catch (err) {
            cwd = path.dirname(cwd);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Is that the right way to detect config file like babel or eslint did? Or, is
there any better way?

Comment: I remember looking into this once... I can't remember the answer. but rc stands for "run commands" :)